# Querying for attribute combinations in Rails - How do I make 9 queries into 1?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

Is there any way to condense these queries down to one query?

I am querying 1 table for 4 attributes: `author_id`, `status`, `category_id`, and `site_id`.  The goal is, I want to find the most recent record in each case (reason is to increment counters for reporting):

```
# author_id
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1

# author_id + status
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'draft' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'published' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1

# author_id + site_id
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.site_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1

# author_id + status + site_id
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'draft' AND posts.site_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'published' AND posts.site_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1

# author_id + site_id + category_id
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.site_id = 1 AND posts.category_id = 7 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1

# author_id + status + site_id + category_id
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'draft' AND posts.site_id = 1 AND posts.category_id = 7 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = 10 AND posts.status = 'published' AND posts.site_id = 1 AND posts.category_id = 7 ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
```

That's 9 queries.  I am doing this in rails, so the goal would be to have 9 `Post` models from one `Post.all(:conditions => x)` call, then I can filter through them in the ruby code.  Is this possible?  What's the best approach here?

**Update**

Here is roughly the code I'm using to generate these queries:

https://gist.github.com/965233

Comment: Can you post the Ruby that you wrote which generates all these SQL calls?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need it in one SQL statement? I'm pretty sure the resulting SQL will be ugly

Comment: updated with a link to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/965233) showing the ruby code generating those db calls.

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL side you can use UNION to combine queries that have a matching list of fields. Add a field to sort them and wrap it all in another query to sort by that. Then you can iterate over the result set.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(    
  SELECT 1 QNO, * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE A=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 QNO, * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE A=1 AND B=2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 QNO, * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE A=2 AND B=4 AND C=11
) 
ORDER BY QNO;
```